# Text reverses on remote gnome session

Tags: gnome, keyboard, ssh, session, text

I have two computers running 10.4 .   The first machine is a wired desktop with sshd.  The second is a wifi connected laptop with the ssh client.  When I use my laptop to bring up a remote gnome session to my desktop all the text gets reversed.

**Steps:**

1) login as a user on the laptop to activate the wifi with a stored key.

2) goto a console <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>

3) do a `xterm -- :1` to bring up a blank graphic session

4) `ssh -Y user@desktopmachine gnome-session`

This shows reversed text and messes up the keyboard so I can't type

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I had the parameter for xinit wrong.
The following is correct:

1) login as a user on the laptop to activate the wifi with a stored key.

2) goto a console <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>

3) do a `xterm -- :2` to bring up a blank xterm session

4) `ssh -Y user@desktopmachine gnome-session`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to connect per ssh

- from the desktop to the desktop
- from the laptop to the laptop

and see, whether the problem occurs there too?

Comment: The problem only exists when I bring up a full graphics gnome-session on another machine.  I think it is gnome-session interfering with itself since I can bring up individual applications remotely without issue but can't bring up a full session without the text reversing.

Comment: I did some more searching and this might be a bug in gnome.  Here is a reference to what I found: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-list/2010-February/msg00021.html